# Why is Networkx's Dijkstra faster than Boost's?

Tags: c++, networkx, dijkstra, boost-graph

I started using Dijkstra's algorithm in python using Networkx, but now I want to speed up my code using c++ and I chose Boost to work with graphs. My surprise was that I didn't see any speed up and that actually Python was faster in calculating the shortest paths. I am very novice to c++ so I don't know if I am doing anything wrong. Here's a sample code that reproduces the problem:

Python code:

```
import networkx as nx
import csv
import time
import numpy as np

def write_graph_to_csv(G):
    # Open a CSV file in write mode
    with open('/Users/robertbenassai/Documents/UOC/k_shortest_path_betweenness/KSP_cpp/graph.csv', 
              'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        # Create a CSV writer object
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    
        # Write the header row (optional)
        csvwriter.writerow(['vertex1', 'vertex2', 'edge_weight'])
    
        # Write edges and their weights to the CSV file
        for u, v, weight in G.edges(data='length'):
            csvwriter.writerow([u, v, weight])

    print('Graph has been written to graph.csv')


graph = nx.random_geometric_graph(100, 0.2)
pos_RG = nx.get_node_attributes(graph, 'pos')
edge_lens = {edge: np.linalg.norm(np.array(pos_RG[edge[1]]) - np.array(pos_RG[edge[0]])) for edge 
              in graph.edges}

nx.set_edge_attributes(graph, edge_lens, name = 'length')

nx.draw_networkx(graph, pos_RG)


times_del = []
for i in range(100):
    t1 = time.time()
    nx.single_source_dijkstra(graph, 1, weight = "length")
    times_del.append(time.time()-t1)
    # print(time.time()-t1)
print(np.mean(times_del))

write_graph_to_csv(graph)
```

C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <numeric>

#include <boost/property_map/dynamic_property_map.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/property_map.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std::chrono;

struct NodeProperties {
    int id;

};

typedef boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::listS,                
    boost::vecS,                 
    boost::undirectedS,          
    NodeProperties,              
    boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double> 
> Graph;

// typedef adjacency_list<listS, vecS, undirectedS,
//     no_property, property<edge_weight_t, double> > Graph; 

typedef graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
typedef graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor Edge;
typedef std::pair<int, int> EdgePair;

int main() {

    /*
    
    READING CSV FILE: EDGE[0], EDGE[1], WEIGHT

    */

    Graph delaunay(0);

    std::ifstream file("graph.csv");
    std::string line;
    std::getline(file, line);

    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        boost::tokenizer<boost::escaped_list_separator<char>> tokens(line);
        auto tokenIterator = tokens.begin();
        int vertex1 = std::stoi(*tokenIterator++);
        int vertex2 = std::stoi(*tokenIterator++);
        double weight = std::stod(*tokenIterator);
        // Add edge to the graph with the given weight
        Edge e = add_edge(vertex1, vertex2, delaunay).first;
        put(edge_weight, delaunay, e, weight);
        // boost::add_edge(vertex1, vertex2, EdgeProperties{weight}, delaunay);
    }


    std::vector<int> path(num_vertices(delaunay), -1);  // Initialize path with -1 for all vertices
    std::vector<double> distances(num_vertices(delaunay));  // Store distances for Dijkstra's algorithm
    std::vector<double> times(100);
    for (int i = 0; 100>i; i++){
        auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

        boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(delaunay, 1,
                                    predecessor_map(make_iterator_property_map(path.begin(), get(vertex_index, delaunay)))
                                    .distance_map(make_iterator_property_map(distances.begin(), get(vertex_index, delaunay))));
        
        auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<float> deltat = (t2 - t1);
        std::cout << "Dijkstra time: "
        << deltat.count() << " seconds" << std::endl;
        times[i] = deltat.count();
    }
    double mean_t = std::accumulate(times.begin(), times.end(), 0.0) / times.size();
    printf("mean time: %lf", mean_t);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried running different graphs but the "problem" persists. Can someone try it and see if it is just me?

**EDIT:**

I am using a makefile to compile it:

```
INC_DIRS = /opt/homebrew/include
LIB_DIRS = /opt/homebrew/lib

CPPFLAGS += -std=c++17

# Link igraph and other libraries
LDFLAGS = -ligraph -lboost_filesystem -lboost_graph

Yen: k_shortest_paths.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(INC_DIRS) -L$(LIB_DIRS) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm Yen
```

I am using C++17 as seen in the makefile. My computer is a MacBoock Pro, M1 chip,sonoma 14.0

Comment: Are you compiling your C++ code with optimizations?

Comment: Am I overlooking the times or are you keeping them secret?

Comment: What is your command line for compiling your C++ code?  With which compiler?  On what platform?

Comment: Any questions that concern the speed of a C++ program must be accompanied by compiler and compiler options used to build the program.  The most important of these options are the optimization setting(s) used.  If you are running an unoptimized or "debug" build, the timings you are showing are meaningless.

Comment: Can you share the CSV for comparisons? Never mind noticed that the python writes a random graph csv.

Comment: (sticking to Python, you may want to try scipy, ISTR that it was faster than networkx on most operations they had in common)

Comment: @KellyBundy I have added timings in my answer. It doesn't reproduce the OP's findings though.

Comment: Besides the mean, also show `print(np.sort(times_del))`. I have a suspicion.

Comment: I see you edited. Why are you still not telling us the times?

Comment: Why are you linking igraph if you are not using it? If you are looking to implement Yen's algorithm for k shortest paths, igraph already has it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I reproduced it, slightly modifying output for readability:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e0740f4789da551c)** (with `graph.csv` from [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bdac555c76f13356))

```
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;

struct NodeProperties {
    int id;
};

typedef boost::adjacency_list<                    //
    boost::listS,                                 //
    boost::vecS,                                  //
    boost::undirectedS,                           //
    NodeProperties,                               //
    boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double> //
    >
    Graph;

// typedef adjacency_list<listS, vecS, undirectedS,
//     no_property, property<edge_weight_t, double> > Graph;

static Graph read_csv(std::string const& fname) {
    /* READING CSV FILE: EDGE[0], EDGE[1], WEIGHT */
    Graph g;

    std::ifstream file(fname);
    file.ignore(1024, '\n');
    std::istringstream iss;

    for (std::string line; std::getline(file, line);) {
        iss.clear();
        iss.str(line);
        char   comma;
        size_t vertex1, vertex2;
        double weight;
        if (iss >> vertex1 >> comma && comma == ',' && //
            iss >> vertex2 >> comma && comma == ',' && //
            iss >> weight) {
            /*auto [ok, e] =*/add_edge(vertex1, vertex2, {weight}, g);
        }
    }

    return g;
}

int main() {
    Graph g = read_csv("graph.csv");

    std::vector<int>         path(num_vertices(g));
    std::vector<double>      distances(num_vertices(g));
    std::vector<long double> times(100);

    for (auto& timing : times) {
        auto start = now();

        boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(
            g, 1,
            predecessor_map(make_iterator_property_map(path.begin(), get(boost::vertex_index, g)))
                .distance_map(make_iterator_property_map(distances.begin(), get(boost::vertex_index, g))));

        timing = (now() - start) / 1.us;
        // std::cout << "Dijkstra time: " << timing << "μs" << std::endl;
    }
    auto mean_t = std::accumulate(times.begin(), times.end(), 0.0l) / times.size();
    std::cout << "Mean time: " << mean_t << "μs" << std::endl;
}
```

Local comparison for several random graphs shows a consistent performance gain of >85x

| python ms | c++ μs | python μs | speed up factor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.501399040222168 | 5.91381 | 501.399040222168 | 84.8 |
| 0.570063591003418 | 6.66114 | 570.063591003418 | 85.6 |
| 0.5150175094604492 | 5.76435 | 515.017509460449 | 89.3 |
| 0.6315255165100098 | 6.66467 | 631.52551651001 | 94.8 |
| 0.581965446472168 | 7.20989 | 581.965446472168 | 80.7 |
| 0.5532622337341309 | 6.14693 | 553.262233734131 | 90.0 |
| 0.6145501136779785 | 5.95821 | 614.550113677979 | 103.1 |
| 0.5210447311401367 | 6.02458 | 521.044731140137 | 86.5 |
| 0.5892086029052734 | 6.33592 | 589.208602905273 | 93.0 |
| 0.7422637939453125 | 6.22005 | 742.263793945313 | 119.3 |

[image]

### IMPROVING

You can improve it further by getting rid of unused inefficiencies:

```
using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<              //
    boost::vecS,                                  // was: boost::listS,
    boost::vecS,                                  //
    boost::undirectedS,                           //
    boost::no_property,                           // was: NodeProperties
    boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, double> //
    >;
```

Also simplifying the property maps (likely no difference due compiler inlining it all to the same code anyways):

```
    dijkstra_shortest_paths(                //
        g, 1,                               //
        boost::predecessor_map(path.data()) //
            .distance_map(distances.data()));
```

> *Full listing on [Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/481f5a533723bc57)*

Which leads to an average speedup factor of 109x:

| python ms | c++ μs | speed up factor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.552058219909668 | 5.02216 | 109.924458780618 |
| 0.5580687522888184 | 4.90002 | 113.891117238056 |
| 0.5484175682067871 | 5.17212 | 106.03341921819 |
| 0.569157600402832 | 5.07291 | 112.195485510847 |
| 0.5981898307800293 | 5.51395 | 108.486625881633 |
| 0.5295181274414062 | 4.87289 | 108.666135997613 |
| 0.5545711517333984 | 5.02684 | 110.322021734012 |
| 0.554049015045166 | 5.11177 | 108.38692176001 |
| 0.5611848831176758 | 5.23707 | 107.15626927226 |
| 0.5605340003967285 | 5.25329 | 106.701514745375 |

Comment: In fact since none of the output maps are used, you can skip them entirely: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a16d79640058d675 (which does not appear to significantly alter runtime cost)

Comment: Great!  I often tell people who are struggling to shave a few millisecs off their python code that switching to C++ is the way to go if they really care about performance.  Good to have independent confirmation.

Comment: In the interest of answering "Why is it slower?" it could be useful to know what the timings are without optimization. Not understanding how that works is a common issue with newer coders asking about speed differences.

Comment: @RetiredNinja anecdotally, just saw 518µs vs 10µs. You could also just edit the links: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7438983008ef3d4 which shows a similar slowup

Comment: @RetiredNinja No I am not compiling with optimizations

Comment: @Eljay I am using a makefile. INC_DIRS = /opt/homebrew/include
LIB_DIRS = /opt/homebrew/lib

CPPFLAGS += -std=c++17

# Link igraph and other libraries
LDFLAGS = -ligraph -lboost_filesystem -lboost_graph

Yen: k_shortest_paths.cpp
 $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(INC_DIRS) -L$(LIB_DIRS) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
 rm Yen

Comment: That's a recipe, but the command line depends on the variables. E.g. you'd expect the optimization flags to be in `CFLAGS`. Just, add them or print the full commands (e.g. using `make -Bsn`) to see what is actively there. In other words: the only thing that matters is _the concrete commands being used_. Don't hide behind your build tools :)

Comment: @RobertBenassai As others have said, if you are not compiling with optimizations on any speed comparisons are meaningless.

Comment: @sehe Thank you for your patience! I used `make -Bsn`and `got c++  -std=c++17 -I/opt/homebrew/include -L/opt/homebrew/lib -ligraph -lboost_filesystem -lboost_graph k_shortest_paths.cpp -o Yen`. Were you using any optimization in your answer? I am still intrigued about why is your case so much faster.

Comment: @RobertBenassai I actually showed the exact commands used, because I have online demos (every Coliru link shows the exact commands to build and run)! You can just copy and paste, in all likelihood. Otherwise, just add something like `CFLAGS+=-O3 -ffast-math` in your makefile

Comment: @sehe Sorry!!!! yes, now I tried it that way and it improved massively! thank you so much!!

Comment: Good news. We are, in the interest of science, of course curious what the timing difference is. I posted [mine above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77274732/why-is-networkxs-dijkstra-faster-than-boosts/77275293?noredirect=1#comment136232754_77275293), so basically 50x - Is it similar?

Comment: @sehe yes. In python it takes around 0.2ms and in C++ around 5µs, so overall a 40x improvement only by putting the optimization `-O3 -ffast-math`.